# Progress bar for custom code (no file upload)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I would like more information about progress bars.
I know they work with a file to upload because you know its size. But what if I have no file but some code to execute with jquery/ajax and I'd like to show the progress with a progress bar. Is it possible?
To give you more details, my code fetches many data on several websites, transform them and finally save them into a database.

**Edit:** Here is an example of my ajax call:

```
function submit_form(form, link, file, button)
{
    var form_data = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: link,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: form_data,
        success: function(result)
        {
             handle_result(form, result, link, button);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [jQueryUI Progressbar docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar) say that you can set the value of a progress bar yourself:

```
$( ".selector" ).progressbar( "value", 50 );
```

So, one way to solve your problem:  if you know the number of operations (fetch data, transform, write to database) you are doing, then you can increment the value of your Progressbar every time one of them finishes:

```
var completed = 0;
var total = 10;

doSomething().done(function(result) {
  completed++;
  $("#progress-bar").progressbar("value", 100 * (completed / total));
});
```

Comment: So let's say I have 10 operations to perform... Does it mean I have to do 10 ajax calls?!! The `done` is called once a call to ajax is finished, right?

Comment: `done()` is a property of a Promise object.  `$.ajax()` returns a Promise object, you're right, but so do a lot of other things.  But Promises are just one way of telling when an operation is complete.  You're the programmer - you can bump up `completed` and redraw your scrollbar whenever you decide an operation is complete.

Comment: Not sure to understand... I call my ajax function once to perform all my operations. Does it mean I can only show 0 and 100% on my progress bar? Should I make one ajax call for each task to perform? Inside my program, can I send back a message to ajax once a single operation operation has been performed?

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [xhr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644418/jquery-ajax-option-xhr) option for $.ajax() function and XMLHttpRequest object. What you need to focus on is adding 'progress' event listener to it. You may also try some ready-made solution like [Reload Progress Bar](http://eiotec.com/reloadprogressbar) plugin for jquery, which extends the $.ajax() function, so that you can use progress bars with any Ajax request.

Comment: I guess you were talking of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11888855/1875861. As far as I understand, you can assess the progress by measuring `xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-length')`. This can be used for an upload or download of a file only, right? In my case, I perform many operations in the background and return a success message only. Can it be used?